# Why didn't kohanim undress themselves?

Tags: clothing, kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash, maseches-tamid

The *mishna*, [*Tamid* 5:3](//www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Tamid.5.3), indicates that those *kohanim* who had gotten dressed for the day's work but were not needed for it would be stripped of their *kohen*-clothes by the Temple workers.

My kid asked: Why didn't they undress themselves?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like the [Tifferes Yisroel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9677&st=&pgnum=160) (Yochin 14) there understands this to mean that the Temple workers were there to take the clothes back from them and return them to storage - and not that they actually physically removed the clothes from their bodies.

Answer (score 4):

At least one of the garments required assistance in dressing/undressing - the אבנט (the belt), which was 32 amos long (more than 48 feet)! Also, the winding of the head covering would probably also require assistance.

The Mishnah in Shekalim 5:2 mentions "Pinchas the Dresser", and the gemara [Yerushalmi Shekalim 22b](http://kodesh.snunit.k12.il/b/r/r2505_022b.htm) says that he dressed the Kohen Gadol.

Comment: Is this your own logic (because it was long, it must have required assistance), or is there a source for it? Note that, IIRC, _mishnayos Yoma_ make it sound like (though don't say explicitly that) the _kohen gadol_ undressed without assistance.

Comment: @msh210 - I think I saw it a very long time ago, but I'm not certain.

Comment: I don't know about undoing a sash, but Sikh men wear turbans about as long as the avnet and much wider and they manage to tie and untie themselves. Source--I thought they looked cool so I learned how.